# THREE.js zoom in mouse direction in case of orthographic camera

Tags: three.js, orthographic

I am working on *THREE.js* **orthographic camera**, I am using 'OrbitalControls.js' for controls.
I want to zoom in the direction of mouse in 3D  world. Hoping to get solution in JS. I know this one is not easy solution like perspective camera.(where we add in camera direction)

Comment: Since there is no fov, you could use a scaling matrix.

Comment: It's not optimal, but you could attach a `PerspectiveCamera` to `OrbitControls`, and then copy its position/quaternion from the `PerspectiveCamera` into your `OrthographicCamera` before you render each frame.

Comment: Could you include some code showing what you've tried so far, or a more detailed explanation of what you mean by "in the direction of mouse" here? Any similar examples?

Comment: Yes please define `zoom in the direction of mouse`, is it zoom around point?

Comment: If you really need to zoom on mouse position, you need a couple of things 1 you need to close scene inside of skycube or skydome and raycast mouse position on it, to define where the camera should zoom, Rotate camera on this point an then use camera.zoom. But i hope, you need only to zoom camer ain the direction of sight. thed do camera.zoom https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354574/zooming-camera-in-threejs-without-trackball-controls-or-other-camera-control-lib

Comment: Do you have any code how to use scaling matrix.

@TheJim01 definately i will give it a try lets see how it works.

[link](http://www.tectractys.com/market_globe.html) 
I want this behaviours of zoom you can see if you use mousewheel anywhere on screen it will zoom in that direction (on globe and outside globe) I have tried many approaches i did not achieve desired reults.

Comment: @Martin I have exactly tried this approach and use ray caster on model (not skybox) and set intersected point as control.target but there was some flicker by such code, yes zoom direction is set on that point.

Comment: That's a different kind of zoom. You'll want to define a "direction" vector based on your mouse position, and translate your camera position along that vector. Keep in mind that for this kind of zoom with an orthographic camera, you'll need to adjust your orthographic viewport in order to achieve the proper scaling.

Comment: Hi After researching a lot I found the following algorithm which might be useful for you to.

 1. zoom and pan in orthographic camera is nothing but setting the projection rectangle (i.e. setting camera left,right,top bottom)

 2. challenge is calculate the mid point of camera calculate mouse position (initial and changed) and reset the camera in the manner

 3. I can not expose the code but algorithm is exactly same like depicted in above steps

Answer (score 0):

There is a .zoom parameter on the orthographic camera.

Try setting increasing/decreasing it.

Comment: "in direction of mouse" is the tricky part here, no one knows what it means

Comment: @pailhead [http://www.tectractys.com/market_globe.html](http://www.tectractys.com/market_globe.html) I feel its a basic behaviour in cad (graphics) world. Its there in NX and some other graphic designing tools. But in this example perspective camera is used, can it done by using orthographic camera?

Comment: Hi After researching a lot I found the following algorithm which might be useful for you to.

 1. zoom and pan in orthographic camera is nothing but setting the projection rectangle (i.e. setting camera left,right,top bottom)

 2. challenge is calculate the mid point of camera calculate mouse position (initial and changed) and reset the camera in the manner

 3. I can not expose the code but algorithm is exactly same like depicted in above steps

Comment: Here's a working example. It zooms in towards the mouse cursor, and out towards the center (similar to Solidworks): https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/w3dot0/three.js/blob/973bf1d40ef552dbf19c19654a79f70e2882563d/examples/misc_controls_zoom_to_mouse.html

Comment: @w3dot0 very good example, but just to note that the method only works when the viewport is around the origin

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by figuring out the difference between your current zoom level and the next one, and then by panning in the direction of the mouse.

Your `OrthographicCamera` has a width and hight in world units `camera.right - camera.left` and `camera.top - camera.bottom`. Say you're at zoom level 1, and you zoom to 2, you divide these by two and get the new width and height in world units.

You need to figure out the difference in X Y and pan the camera in that direction.

Comment: Thanks so much I think we are on same page do you have any working example ? I found a beautiful example but the they are taking different camera and coordinate system. [http://bl.ocks.org/nitaku/b25e6f091e97667c6cae/569c5da78cf5c51577981a7e4d9f2dc6252dbeed](http://bl.ocks.org/nitaku/b25e6f091e97667c6cae/569c5da78cf5c51577981a7e4d9f2dc6252dbeed)

Comment: Hi After researching a lot I found the following algorithm which might be useful for you to.

 1. zoom and pan in orthographic camera is nothing but setting the projection rectangle (i.e. setting camera left,right,top bottom)

 2. challenge is calculate the mid point of camera calculate mouse position (initial and changed) and reset the camera in the manner

 3. I can not expose the code but algorithm is exactly same like depicted in above steps